# Android - How can I start a web search and get results to my activity

Tags: android

I want to build an app that receives a phrase from the user, searches for it on the web, and displays the results inside the app (so it will be displayed more comfortably).

So far I managed to start the Google Search but can't get results back to my activity. I tried `StartActivityForResults` but it seems that Google Search doesn't support it.
I want to get the search results in a form of URL list or something similar so I can open it in another activity in my app. any suggestions?

Here is my code so far:

```
public void SearchWeb (View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message); //get text from EditText
    String query = editText.getText().toString();
    query = query.concat(" chords");
    intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, query);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your doing it only allows you to launch the search not to get any results back
you can use [CustomSearch Api](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/customsearch/customsearch/v1/search.cse.list) from google and parse the result with Json

here is a snippet on how to

```
public searchQuery  {
        String key="your API key";
        String qry="Android";// your keyword to search
        URL url = new URL(
                "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?               
                key="+key+"&cx="Replace with unique ID"&q="+ qry + 
                "&alt=json");
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                (conn.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println(url);
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {

            if(output.contains("\"link\": \"")){                
                String link=output.substring(output.indexOf("\"link\": \"")+
                       ("\"link\": \"").length(), output.indexOf("\","));
                System.out.println(link);
            }     
        }
        conn.disconnect();   
    }
```